# Secure Sessions - Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, file, security, session

I would like to ask for your advice. I need to store some "secret" data in laravel Session (file). I have a RestID from third party API after call authorize method and I need to store it for another routes (I dont want to call authorize method on each site). I use encrypted Session file, but I dont know if it's "secure". Is it ok, or it's another (better) solution for that?

Thank you

Comment: did u find solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you need secure session in Laravel, go to config/session.php and set `true`

```
'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', true),
```

Then clear cache: `php artisan config:cache`

Then use SSL certificate (Let's encrypt is for free). Then your webside will have `https://` element before your domain.

Then in `.htaccess` force to use ssl:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Good luck!